# How to deconstruct this sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning, parsing

> A deep purple lipstick made her look like a vampire, she said to screams, laughter and wefies, before trying out the coral hue and ochre shades.

Why is "said to" followed by nouns like "screams, laughter and wefies" but not verbs like "scream, laugh and take wefies" here?

Can it be written as "To her screams, laughter and wefies, she said that…"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screams, laughter and "wefies" (whatever that is supposed to be) are coming from the other people present. Parse this as:

> ... made her look like a vampire, she said, to [the sound of] screams, laughter...

Comment: Apparently (and I [just learned this](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wefie)) "wefie" is a portmanteau of "we + selfie," i.e. a group portrait. Kids these days ;)

Comment: Hmm, TIL. I've definitely used "selfie" to include group pictures though.